# How to get current server time (unix server) in java?

Tags: java

I want to get current server time (Application running on Unix box) in Java. What is the best way to get current server time in Java/

Comment: is the java application running on the server?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you getting any error? If you want to know just how.. try googling it.

Comment: @Vikdor.. yes Java application running on the Websphere Application Server. I want to get that machine's time.

Comment: @GPS.. I tried Googling it but not getting correct answer :(

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but it's probably because you haven't indicated *what* you've tried, or why it didn't work.

Comment: Could you expand on what exactly you are looking for?  Are you looking for the time of day, datetime stamp, millis since epoch?

Comment: I am looking for current server's date and time in milliseconds format... @allingeek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for previous post,

This is a correct one:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
String output = dateFormat.format(date); 
System.out.println(output);
```

And prints :

> 27/09/2012 09:42:36

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will accept this as answer. Is there anyway I can convert output into milliseconds?

Comment: Thanks, I got the answer... :) and I don't have enough rep to upvote.. sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get is like this

```
long unixTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;

String inString=String.valueOf(unixTime);

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

String output = inString.format(dateFormat);
```

Comment: I tried your code, when I run it gave me output as "1348727677" and when I convert it to date format it is giving me "Friday, January 16, 1970 9:38:47 AM EST" where as what I want is today's date time

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is create a new Date.

```
import java.util.Date;
...
long millisSinceEpoch = (new Date()).getTime();
```